# Data is not showing in textarea

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

This is my code

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group form-row {{ $errors->has('alamat_pengiriman') ? 'has-danger' : '' }}">
        <label for="permintaan-jenis-alamat-p" class="col-12 col-xl-5 col-form-label">Alamat Pengiriman</label>
        <div class="col-12 col-xl-7">
            <textarea id="alamat_pengiriman" class="custom-input form-control {{ $errors->has('alamat_pengiriman') ? 'form-control-danger' : '' }}" name="alamat_pengiriman" style="height: 90px;" required>{{ old('alamat_pengiriman') }}</textarea>
            @if ($errors->has('alamat_pengiriman'))
                {!! lgk_print_message($errors, 'alamat_pengiriman') !!}
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But still the textarea doesn't show the message I put.

Thank you for the helping.

Comment: I feel like we're missing a lot of code here. Can we have any / all functionality associated with `lgk_print_message` ?

Comment: when its not showing the message?? after the validation failing??

Comment: Use like this `{{{ Input::old('alamat_pengiriman') }}}`